# On words with non-Classical meanings in LLPSI

Tags: vocabulary

I found *Lingua Latina per se Illustrata*(LLPSI) use the word **kalendārium** for *calendar* (as in Chap. 13, and the official Latin-English wordbook), but in both dictionaries *L&S* and *OLD* there is just one meaning *account book* (*calendar* seems to be a later usage). Besides, I found the word **capitulum** for *chapter* is not that Classical either (according to dictionaries), while the Classical word should be **caput**.

Is there any more non-Classical usages in this series? (except those in post-Classical original texts)

Comment: The Gaffiot dictionary does give "chapter" as a possible translation for capitulum: https://gaffiot.fr/#1%20capitulum

Comment: @Florianus yes, and their reference is the Codex Iustinianus (6th century).

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel but isn't capitulum just the diminutive of caput? In that case, it could sound a bit weird, but pretty understandable...

Comment: (but still)....